# Possible to create an inline-block that isn't actually inline?

Tags: html, css

I often find that I want an element to adjust its width to the size of the elements it contains. `inline-block` acheives this. However, I do NOT want the `inline` part of `inline-block` -- i.e., I still want the next `inline-block` element to appear below it.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in CSS? I know I can't always but `<br>` tags after the element in my HTML, but that's annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many solutions, the most common one is to use float

```
<div class="float">
  <div class="child">here is content</div>
</div>

.float{float: left;}
```

if you want enforce that an element is in the new line you add clear: both (or left or right, depending on your needs)

please take into account, that display: inline-block does not work in IE7. The only problem with float is when you want this div to adjust to the width of a child AND to position it at the middle of the page horizontaly

one more note, remember that overflow: hidden property is your best friend whenever you encounter any issues with floated divs :)

Comment: Thanks. This offers the simplest solution to my problem. I generally avoid floats like the plague, but I guess they can have their use :)

Comment: @maxedison I can't remember any project in which I did not use floats, what is the reason that you avoid them? they are the most useful thing I know

Comment: Eh, I suppose the whole concept of a float always felt shaky to me. In general I'm not a major fan of CSS's layout model. I'm sure there are plenty of places where floats come in handy. I just decided one day that I was angry at them and have stayed away ever since :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with two elements:

```
<div>
    <div class="element">
        content...
    </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS rule:

```
.element { display: inline-block; }
```

Treat `.element` as the "real" element that you're adjusting the width of. The enclosing `<div>` is just there to force each element into its own inline flow.

Comment: but the parent element will take 100% width so it is not an answer to the question ?

Comment: True. Whether that makes a difference would depend on the context.

Comment: "I often find that I want an element to adjust its width to the size of the elements it contains." :)

Comment: The inner element (`div.element`) has `display:inline-block`, so *its* width will adjust to its content just fine. The outer `div` is just there to control how the inner elements get laid out; its width doesn't really matter in most cases.

Comment: well in my opinion if it wouldn't matter then you would not need to wrap it in .element div, right? what sense is to create div with width equals to its content if it does not matter?

Comment: To keep the `inline-block` elements from being displayed on the same line as one another.

Comment: and we come to the point: why would you make an inline-block element in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that achieves what you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/VwCgJ/

It uses floating elements (thus width is ajusted to content), a class on the last element you want on a line and the `clear` property on the next element, with the help of the adjacent selector `.rightmost + span`

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    <span>lorem</span>
    <span class="rightmost">ipsum</span>
    <span>third item: below please</span>
    <span>fourth and last</span>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: lightblue;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.rightmost {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.rightmost + span {
    clear: both;
}
```

Inline content (as for inline-block) will occupy the whole width of its container and you've to force a new line with the br element.
On the other side, floating elements can be cleared (and with adjacent selector, you can clear the element after a particular one).